# Profile pictures not displaying in forum

Tags: media, users

I am making my first forum using Drupal and have very little web development experience.  My forum is very basic so far, mostly using core modules.

I tried adding a profile picture for my admin account (and also a picture for a test user account), but the image doesn't show anywhere.  I only get the thumbnail that indicates a missing file or broken link.  I have tried reloading the page, clearing the cache, and installing the profile2 module, but of course I still do not see images.  I have since uninstalled profile2 just because I want to keep the forum as simple as possible until I learn more.

I'm working in version 7.39 and the site is hosted on my university account.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Eric

Comment: What browser r u using? I experienced same problem in Chrome. Can you make right-click on image? Is it appearing after click?

Comment: I am using Opera, but because you asked, I tried Firefox and Internet Explorer.  None of them display the image.  Only Firefox seems to recognize that it should be an image (I get options for images if I right-click, whereas the other Browsers do not).  If I "view image info" using Firefox, it describes it as "Type: text/html", "Size: unknown", and "Dimensions: 0px x 0px".

Answer (score 1):

I had also posted my question to my university drupal help list and managed to find an answer.  I don't know how much of this applies to the general community (it may only apply to my specific Drupal install at my university because they include automated configuration adjustments), but here is the solution that worked for me:

My main folder is called simply drupal.  In the file

*/drupal/.htaccess*

I had changed the line

*Options +FollowSymLinks*

to instead read

*Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch*

The problem was that I had not changed a second copy of this file in another location:

*/drupal/sites/default/files/.htaccess*

I made the same changes to this file and now the images show.  I did not simple copy one file to the other location, because the files contain different options and only the one line needed a change.  Again, my drupal install might be unique to my university, but these edits are so minor that I think someone else could try them without getting into too much trouble.  Maybe someone else could lend more insight if needed.